# posix_memalign or aligned_alloc?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, posix

I would like to align the memory in order to optimise a matrix multiplication. So far I have managed to allow it to do multiplications line times line in order to make better use of cache. In order to increase the cache hit rate I would like to align the memory. This is where I have seen that there are two ways of doing so: `posix_memalign` and `aligned_alloc`. I wanted to ask here in order to know which would be best to use.

Comment: "Best to use" is very subjective. Do you feel like anything is wrong with the robust `aligned_alloc`?

Comment: @Edenia do you think there's anything wrong with posix_memalign?

Comment: Not a real concern besides that it isn't standard.

Comment: @Edenia oh, i didn't know that, should i just stick with standard?

Comment: Unless there is some very specific requirement on your platform then sure. I think `posix_memalign` was handled differently in terms of the return value. So maybe check the posix refpage and see what complies best with your requirements and practice? Both yield same result, but differ in implementation details.

Comment: You get to choose between Standard C (which, as of C11, provides `aligned_alloc()`, but which is not necessarily available everywhere) and Standard POSIX (which, as of POSIX 2004, provides `posix_memalign()`).  Two standards — two different but basically equivalent functions, even though the interfaces are different (2 arguments for `aligned_alloc()`, 3 for `posix_memalign()`) so they are certainly not drop-in replacements for each other.  You get to choose which standard is most relevant to you.  Microsoft (Windows) probably has an alternative solution, too.

Comment: Microsoft seems to have a number of aligned allocation functions, including [`_aligned_malloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-170).  That's essentially the same as `aligned_alloc()` from the C standard.   A Google search with "site:microsoft.com C aligned memory allocation" shows a lot of options — and the page linked to shows alternatives down the LH margin.